# Is there any possible way to reduce/cut the horizontal time axis gap in LiveChart in Winform?

Tags: c#, charts, livecharts

Since the data may not be available everyday (however the data is continuous), my current chart is showing a lot of gaps between days.

[image: gaps image]

Each point in the series is time related (to second) but I just want to keep the trend and cut the gap without removing the time. Is there anyway to achieve this?